# implementing timer in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

implementing basic timer functionality?should i use for loop or any other loop is possible..

how to print value of x in function "hello()" ? i have already created a delay of 30secs for the function hello.. i just want value of x to be printed like 30secs=value of id>>11, 60secs=value of id>>12, 90secs=value of id>>11, and so on ....

```js
   

 setInterval(() => {
      hello();
    }, 1500)

    const hello = async() => {
      try {
        console.log('-----------');
        var date = new Date().toLocaleString();
        console.log(date, 'printing');
        const value = [{"id":"11"},{"id":"12"}];
        if (value != null) {
          console.log('entered');
          let puburl = value;

          if (puburl != null) {
console.log("puburl",puburl)
            for (let i = 0; i < puburl.length; i++) {
console.log("length",puburl.length)
              let x = puburl[i].id;
              console.log('value of id >>', x);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error: " + e)
      }
    };
```

Comment: FYI - I turned your code into a code snippet, with reduced timeout (1500 instead of 30000, so it runs faster) + error handling (so we see what goes wrong, if anything). It complains that `AsyncStorage` does not exist, please let us know what this is, it does not exist in the browser. Maybe the error handling can also help you figure out what goes wrong on your end.

Comment: Why `let puburl = JSON.parse(value);`? Is not necessary

Comment: @PeterB have changed the code snippet any idea on updated snippet

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes..i have change it any idea on updated snippet?

Comment: So you want to print value of id according to how many times you enter in `hello` function? first time 11, second time 12, third time 11... correct?

Comment: yes every 30 seconds when hello function is called it should print id 11,id 12etc... @GiovanniEsposito

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up some of the extra console logs in the code to make it more clear, but the main thing that you need is some sort of variable keeping track of the index in the array in your interval.

In this case, I made a variable called `counter`.  This variable can keep track of which index in `puburl` we're currently at by using it in the following: `const index = counter++ % puburl.length`.

In this expression, we're doing a few things.  Since we're always going to go through `puburl.length` number of indexes, by using the % operator, we can loop through each of the indexes.  When counter is 0, index will be `0 % puburl.length` which is 0.  When it's 1, index will be 1, and so on.  To make sure we go to the next index, we also shouldn't forget to increment counter after each interval.  Hence the `counter++`.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  hello();
}, 1500)

let counter = 0

const hello = async() => {
  try {
    const date = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log('------ ' + date + ' -----');

    const value = [{
      "id": "11"
    }, {
      "id": "12"
    }];

    if (value != null) {
      const puburl = value;
      
      // You can also reset the value of counter when it equals puburl.length.
      // Not strictly necessary depending on what you're trying to do though.
      if (counter === puburl.length) counter = 0;

      const index = counter++ % puburl.length;
      
      let x = puburl[index].id;
      console.log('value of id >>', x);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error: " + e)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. My solution is using `setInterval`'s args. At first time I call `setInterval(hello, 1500, 0)` passing 0 to hello function (the id index to print). Then in `hello` function I cancel interval, print value and re-create an interval with the new index to print (`++count % puburl.length`)

```js
const hello = (count) => {
  try {
        if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('-----------');
        var date = new Date().toLocaleString();
        console.log(date, 'printing');
        const value = [{"id":"11"},{"id":"12"}];
        if (value != null) {
          console.log('entered');
          let puburl = value;

          if (puburl != null) {
             console.log("puburl",puburl)
             console.log('value of id >>', puburl[count].id);
             
             interval = setInterval(hello, 1500, ++count % puburl.length)
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error: " + e)
      }
};

let interval = setInterval(hello, 1500, 0)
```